# Why are storage classes called classes?

Tags: c, class, storage-class-specifier

auto, register, static and extern are called storage classes in C.
But why are they called classes when there are no classes in C?

Comment: For the same reason why Karl Marx urged to eliminate classes about a century before object-oriented programming.

Comment: @bereal Little has been said about his functional programming advocacy!

Comment: C also has "objects" but not in the object-oriented sense. That's just a general term for "thing you can address and manipulate".

Comment: The word is overloaded, like 'static' or 'interrupt'.  You need additional context to understand a particular meaning:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word "classes" (plural of "class") is [a common English term](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/class) and in this case is being used as such.

> **class**
>
> Pronunciation /klas/ /klæs/
>
> NOUN
>
> A set or category of things having some property or attribute in common and differentiated from others by kind, type, or quality.
>
> > "the accommodations were good for a hotel of this class"
> >
> > "a new class of heart drug"